# Why is Mathf.Clamp() not limiting angles correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D [platformer game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_game) in Unity. I have a `GunController` script that controls the angle of the player's gun:

[image: Player]

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class GunController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float minAngle = -45f;
    public float maxAngle = 45f;

    private void Update ()
    {
        // Get input from up and down arrow keys
        float input = 0;

        if (Keyboard.current.upArrowKey.isPressed) // I'm using Input system package
        {
            input = 1;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.current.downArrowKey.isPressed)
        {
            input = -1;
        }

        // Calculate new rotation based on input and speed
        float newRotation = transform.localEulerAngles.z + (-input * rotationSpeed);

        // Clamp the new rotation to be within the minimum and maximum angles
        newRotation = Mathf.Clamp (newRotation, minAngle, maxAngle);

        // Set the new rotation of the gun
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, newRotation);
    }
}
```

But there's a problem. When the gun reaches the 0 angle, it resets to maximum angle value. For example, when I'm rotating clockwise and the gun's rotation reaches 0, it immediately goes to 120 (which is set as the maximum angle).

[image: Problem]

I've tried this method, but it didn't work:

```
private float ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
        if (angle > 360) angle -= 360;
        return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
    }
```

And I used this method instead of `Mathf.Clamp()` in the component's code.

Comment: Have you tried Debugging the newRotation to see what the results are?

Comment: `newRotation` has no problem & is working well. As I've told, the problem is because of `Clamp` method

Comment: Hmm, have you tried the solution offered in the answer below?

Comment: Yes. And as I commented to him (now removed), his solution was not quite working.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the angle, you can change the value of the angle with the help of `Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle` and then `Clamp` it.

```cs
[SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed = 6;
private float newZ;
void Update()
{
    ...
    if (input != 0)
    {
       newZ = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(newZ, newZ + input, Time.deltaTime * Mathf.PI * rotationSpeed);
       newZ = Mathf.Clamp(newZ, minAngle, maxAngle);
       transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, newZ);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Unity´s Euler angles range from 0 to 360, but you are using a system that ranges from -180 to 180. And you can't prevent Unity from converting the values to its own system when you set an angle with ransform.localEulerAngles.Set(). For this reason, you need to convert the angle you get from transform.localEulerAngles.z back to your system:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float minAngle = -45f;
    public float maxAngle = 45f;

    public float newRotation;

    private void Update()
    {
        // Get input from up and down arrow keys
        float input = 0;

        if (Keyboard.current.upArrowKey.isPressed) // I'm using Input system package
        {
            input = 1;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.current.downArrowKey.isPressed)
        {
            input = -1;
        }

        // Calculate new rotation based on input and speed
        newRotation = ShiftAngle(transform.localEulerAngles.z) + (-input * rotationSpeed);

        // Clamp the new rotation to be within the minimum and maximum angles
        newRotation = Mathf.Clamp(newRotation, minAngle, maxAngle);

        // Set the new rotation of the gun
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, newRotation);
    }

    float ShiftAngle(float a)
    {
        if (a > 180) a -= 360;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of issues in the past when trying to modify existing angles, because you're reading and writing the angles as Euler angles, but Unity's internal rotation representation is Quaternion. This means that the angles you read will depend on Unity's conversion from Quaternion to Euler angles, which may not be consistent with the values you write. You could write a value of 360 degrees and when you read it you might get zero. When you write 270 degrees do you get 270 when you read it, or do you get -90? Etc.

The best solution for me personally in the past has been to just track my own angles. If all you're doing is reading a rotation, modifying it, and then writing that rotation, then track those angles on your own and use that instead of ever polling the object for its rotation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class GunController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float minAngle = -45f;
    public float maxAngle = 45f;
    public float currentAngle = 0f;

    private void Update ()
    {
        // Get input from up and down arrow keys
        float input = 0;

        if (Keyboard.current.upArrowKey.isPressed) // I'm using Input system package
        {
            input = 1;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.current.downArrowKey.isPressed)
        {
            input = -1;
        }

        // Calculate new rotation based on input and speed
        currentAngle += -input * rotationSpeed;

        // Clamp the new rotation to be within the minimum and maximum angles
        currentAngle = Mathf.Clamp (currentAngle, minAngle, maxAngle);

        // Set the new rotation of the gun
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, currentAngle);
    }
}
```